# Reverse order in ElasticSearch when zero_terms_query

Tags: elasticsearch, mongoosastic

I use elasticsearch on a main page. Now you can search and everything works perfect.

As an initial I use `'zero_terms_query': 'all` which shows all the results in insertion order. I'd however prefer to see the lastest rather than the oldest ones shown. I think I can not change the order for all the query since the search query are already in a good order.

How can I change the order of this query? Or how to "reverse insert" in elaticsearch?

Thanks

Comment: I don't get it. What's your query and what do you mean by "shows all the results in insertion order"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sort`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html) to specify how you want your results to be sorted. You need to use a field that contains the notion of "latest vs oldest", usually people use a date or timestamp field for that:

```
{
   "sort": {
      "your_timestamp" : "desc"
   },
   "query": {
      "match": {...}
   }
}
```